# Ware/Wares for a domestic warehouse app

Tags: word-usage

Forgive me but I'm Italian and I have difficulty to perceiving the function of the word "ware" in everyday life. I found a similar question here but the responses do not meet my needs.
My goal is to create a smartphone app where you can enter an inventory of objects of our daily uses. Through a functional search engine will then can look up the stuff that's been posted. For this the name of the app: "WareApp"
The first thing that came to my mind was 'domestic warehouse', hence the word Ware.
I hope these two photos can give a good idea:

[image: Home]
[image: Search engine]

I'm not so far to publish the App but I'm in time to change name and graphics and now my mind has brought forth these questions: is it the right name? will be misinterpreted? Is there something better like Stuff, Article, Record, Object?

Please help, this is not spamming the App is not in the store and also it will be free for anyone.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wares are shady or plain illegal stuff that will destroy your computer, or get you in trouble with the police, or get you in trouble with criminals, or all of the above. Your screenshot is hilarious at best.

Comment: @RegDwigнt That is *warez*; *wares* would be an unusual usage here, but you could use it ironically, since *wares* are the kinds of things you would expect from old-fashioned retail like Sears or Macy's.

Comment: "Forgive me but being Italian" make no apology! The romance, the beaches the fast cars...  ;)

Comment: Please be patient, sometimes I use a translator to write faster...

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Someone might think just like you. The word "ware" is losing points here... Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As someone who works on warehouse and distribution applications used in industry, I would say that "items" would be a better choice in this context than "wares". It works with all the buttons you've shown above, with the possible exception of "checklist wares". If your app is showing a checklist of items then "items checklist" would work better.

A less formal alternative that might be more appropriate for a personal app is "stuff". This is the terms that amazon uses when they invite you to "sell your stuff". ([Link to Amazon sell your stuff example](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Sell-Your-Stuff-on-Amazon/b?ie=UTF8&node=949951031))

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, as I am a programmer I'm using consistently the term "item", I know its meaning and it's certainly in the list of possible winners. The term Stuff is also very interesting. Can I use it in the buttons like "Item"? And a possible title StuffApp sounds good in English? or ItemApp obviously...

Comment: You can directly substitute "wares" for "stuff" in the buttons above with one exception. It's the checklist one again. This time "Stuff checklist" doesn't work. "Stuff" used as verb in English can be mildly rude so it would be better to change the order so it's clearly being used as a noun. You could use "Checklist Stuff" or just "Checklist" for example.

Regarding the title. "StuffApp" is OK. "ItemApp" works but is dull. You could try making the title a question. How about "Where's my stuff?" or "Who has my stuff?"

Comment: After a few days, I am seriously thinking about the word Stuff, as you suggested! In any case, even the word GEAR sounds good together with APP although I couldn't focus it very well, some of my friends insist that it is a term not quite appropriate for this function. May I ask what do you think about?

Comment: Another thing, please ... Changing the term ware with stuff I can also decide to do without the suffix APP. Listening to the pronunciation of StuffApp on the internet I can't figure out whether it can play well or, if so, how much. Can you please help me to understand this too?

Comment: Based on many similar comments I'm definitely addressing Stuff for my app name. Thanks a lot!

Comment: To me it's quite clear how "StuffApp" would be pronounced even though it's not a dictionary word. Just calling it "Stuff" leaves it pretty vague, which could be a good or a bad thing. It might hurt early adoption as it's less clear what your app does, but it leaves open the possibility of expanding the app to do other things, like sell people stuff or help them find buyers for their stuff. If you call it "stuff" and it becomes the next ebay, please buy me a beer.

Comment: Well my friend, I believe that beers will be two, wherever and whenever you like:-) Thanks for your time and for the help.

Answer (score 2):

> I have difficulty perceiving the function of the word "ware" in
> everyday life.

Most native speakers would share your difficulty because it is not a word used in everyday life.

*Ware* or *wares* (plural) refers to *manufactured articles of a specified type.* - [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ware).

The definition has the following expanded examples of the usage:

> ‘When selecting a present for a family, utilitarian kitchen items,
> including cutlery and crystal ware, are often the best choice.’
>
> ‘Crystal ware was the theme of the day with eight prizes provided and
> presented by Lady Captain Margaret Rothwell at the evening dinner for
> 108 competitors and non-playing members.’
>
> ‘It was once home to a factory for manufacturing plastic ware.’
>
> ‘Separate areas were devoted
> to wares from Arita, Kutani, Seto, Satsuma, and Tokyo.’ etc...

*Ware* is not an everyday word but actually somewhat dated and used to refer to specific types of manufactured articles of the same type.

Ware is not a great name for your app, because it does not relate to the wide variety of items pictured in your app as the word is used to refer to a specific collection of items that are of the same type. E.g. Crystal ware, leather ware. etc...

(Despite what this ebay user would have you believe):

[image]

*General ware* is a contradiction in terms.

Turning to words you might use to describe the wide variety of items a person may have in their possession, here are three suggestions:

*Belongings, possessions, valuables.*

I like valuables for your described usage as it has the connotation that the items are in fact valuable to the person that owns them.

> Things that are worth a lot of money, especially small personal things
> such as jewellery, cameras, etc. -- [Oxford](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/valuables)

Idiomatically the word *valuables* is used to refer to any possession that is dear to someone not just a possession that is worth a great sum of money.

This would serve well from your app perspective, because people would be reminded how valuable their items are and it may encourage them to download your app to protect them.

However, there is a caveat the use of *valuables* might lead your potential users to believe the app was *only* for valuable items, if this a risk you wanted to avoid, you might use:

***[Gear](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gear)***

(which has quite an edgy connotation to it as it's informal):

> 2.2 informal Personal possessions and clothes.
>
> ‘I told her to come back to my place with all her gear’

-- Oxford

Gear is also shorter than valuables, which for your specific usage would make it the best choice I would say.

In your picture you refer to 'wareapp options':

[image]

> Valueablesapp options

doesn't have quite the same ring to it as:

> Gearapp options

The fact *gear* is shorter than *valuables* and easier to pronounce, coupled with the informality of the word make *gear* the best choice for your usage I would say.

Comment: Thanks for this great and useful answer. I would like to know if that term can be used successfully also with existing buttons. For example, should I write Add Gears? Explore Gears? Lend Gears? Thanks a lot, really! My daughter is asking me to also add 'make a present' or 'give a gift', to track an object if you decide to give it away, how could I apply it to Gears. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I would say 'ware' is more frequently used these days to describe a range or type of useful product, such as 'glassware' (= wineglasses, tumblers, etc.) and 'software', although it can be used in the sense you describe. 'Goods' might be a useful alternative, as it is broader (would encompass things like the joypads etc. in your images above) and also used for individual items. 
Hope this helps!
Helen

Comment: Yes Helen sure this help! "it can be used in the sense you describe" then this should be ok, apart the fact of Goods might be better?

Answer (score 1):

These things are generally called

> products
>
> definition of product (Oxford): An article or substance that is manufactured or refined for sale.

**Update**:

Now that I've understood better what you are doing, I'll suggest

> **belongings**

Note that the informal word for this is "**stuff**."

> Formal: I have to move my belongings out of my apartment by Monday.  My buddy's going to lend me a truck and I'm going to get it all done on Saturday.
>
> Informal: I have to move my stuff out of my apartment by Monday.  Etc.

Whether to use "belongings" or "stuff" depends on your target audience.

Comment: My app will not contain products for sale. Thanks anyway

Comment: @SteveRogers - Well, then I guess I need to ask for an explanation of what you mean by "wares."  There is a word *ware* and there is a suffix *ware* and they are different. I'll take a wild guess and ask, does your app make an inventory of household objects a person has in their house?

Comment: Yes it will! I imagine my App as a secondary brain where I can store anything I have, material and not. Another name I thought was appropriate in fact is "drawer of memories". To "free" the brain from all the information that can be kept in a Smartphone.

Comment: Then I would suggest *belongings*.  "Ware" really throws an English speaker off.

Comment: Belongings it is truly a very nice term. I created this App as a ' mold ' which will, I hope, be the base for many other more specific (by changing the name, changing some graphics and by adding some field). I hope belongings will be just one of them. Thanks buddy.